# Unable to compile/install PySide 1.2.1 with phonon

Tags: python, qt, pyside, phonon

Yesterday, I tried to compile and install PySide 1.2.1 on Ubuntu 13.10 with no luck. PySide always installs without phonon player. I used to have PySide with phonon on this system, but I have uninstalled it, because I have some issues with code completion in Pycharm. Then when I try to compile/install it again, there is no Phonon. Please help, I am quite frustrated.

I am using this step-by-step guide: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PySide#building-pyside-on-a-unix-system-ubuntu-12-04-13-10

Ubuntu 13.10 x64
Setup tools v1.4.1

Comment: The prerequisites section from that guide does not include any phonon packages. I imagine the build would require `phonon`, `libphonon-dev`, and maybe `phonon-backend-gstreamer`. Do you have them installed?

Comment: ekhumoro is right. I have added the missing libphonon-dev build dependency to guide on https://github.com/PySide/pyside-setup#building-pyside-on-a-unix-system-ubuntu-1204---1310

Comment: Thank you so much. Finally, phonon is included.